# MS-Report Builder 2.0 : Matrix, Column Percentages

Tags: reporting-services

This is doing my head in been searching for hours but either I can't get the question right or can't find anything published.

I have a Report Builder 2 Matrix that returns the following
[image]

There are two groupings: Row Groups: Required Month and Column Groups: EventStatus.

I'm trying to achieve the following (done in excel), where each 'In Time' column is show as a percentage of the total for the row.
For instance Completed in time is calculated as (167/369)*100
[image]

My issue is I cannot find a formula or expression that will enable me to calculate this at run time.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ReportItems collection to reference the actual cells rather than the underlying dataset values.

Insert a column to the right of "In time" inside the group and set the expression to something like

=ReportItems!MyInTimeColumn.Value/ReportItems!MyTotalColumn.Value*100

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you kindly mark the answer as accepted if you are happy with it. Thanks.

Comment: Thought I had...must have double clicked..all done now